# Reproductive property of multivariate normal distribution in the context of multiple regression model(intuition):

Tags: multiple-regression, multivariate-normal-distribution

**Reproductive property:**

Let $Z \sim N_m(\mu,\Sigma)$ and $A$ be a $[l\times m]$ matrix with $\operatorname{rank}(A) = l$.

Then:
$AZ + a \sim N_l\left(A \mu + a,A \Sigma A^T\right)$.

I understand the technical part of proof, but I didn't understand the intuition behind this theorem. So, I have a couple of questions:

1) Why do we care about multiplication of our randim variable $Z$ by **matrix** $A$(rather than vector). How does it look in real world problem?(or at least some theoretical examples, that will provide intuition).

2) Why do we need the rank of matrix $A$ to be $l$?

I hope to receive some good explanations in context of multiple regression analysis.

Comment: what is reproductive property ?

Comment: Statement at the beginning(edited)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1)** Many theorems are proven without any "intuition drive", and researchers try for as much generality as possible. So if we can have the reproductive property for a matrix why confine ourselves to the case of a vector (which is a matrix restricted to have one of its dimensions equal to unity)?

Note that $Z$ is a random vector. If $\mathbf a$ is a $1 \times m$ vector $\mathbf aZ$ will be a uni-dimensional random variable. $AZ$ will be instead a $l \times 1$ random vector, so we are proving the reproductive property for vectors, which gives us more modelling options.

**2)**  We need $A$ to be of rank $l\;$  because $A\Sigma A^T$ will have the rank of $A$ (lookup linear algebra) and we want this Variance-Covariance matrix to have full rank (and so be non-singular)

Comment: Since $Z$ is an $m$-vector and $A$ is an $l\times m$ matrix, $AZ$ is an $l$-vector.  That could be construed a "random matrix" only in the trivial sense that the vector could be considered an $l\times 1$ matrix.

Comment: @whuber Oh, what nonsense did I write... Corrected.

Comment: @AlecosPapadopoulos Thank you for the anwser! If it is not hard for you, can you provide some examples(for bivariate normal r.v) or explain in words, in which way $AZ$ gives us more modelling options?

Comment: @DanielYefimov ...in an analogous way that multiple regession provides more modelling options compared to simple regression.